# i18: Combine localization files from multiple dependencies

Tags: java, spring, localization, dependencies

In my Spring project, I have a resources, which needs localization. The project consist out of a `base` package and multiple additional packages which can build up on each others. In the end I have one main project, which simply declares the all necessary dependencies (The `base` module is mandatory).

The resource which needs translation is a journal event id. Each module defines its own journal events dependently. Meaning each module will end up having `journal_messages` properties for the translation.

```
main
|_ dependencies
    |
    |-moduleA
    |     |_`journal_messages_de.properties`
    |     |_`journal_messages_en.properties`
    |
    |-moduleB
          |_`journal_messages_de.properties`
          |_`journal_messages_en.properties`
```

In the main project I finally need access to all of those files. 
As I'm working with `Spring` I tried the following approach:

My `base` module creates the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` bean:

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource journalMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:com/project/base/i18/journal/journal_messages");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
```

and also having it's own files in `main\resources\com\project\base\i18\journal`

In my other modules I created a config file to add the specific basename of this module.

```
@Autowired
public void addResources(ResourceBundleMessageSource journalMessageSource) {
    journalMessageSource.addBasenames("classpath:com/project/moduleA/i18/journal/journal_messages");
}
```

having it's own files in `main\resources\com\project\moduleA\i18\journal`

This way I've expected that each module would load it's own localization files to the shared `ResourceBundleMessageSource` bean. Altought this leads to

`ResourceBundle [com/project/moduleA/i18/journal/journal_messages] not found for MessageSource`

How can I access/use my localization files which are split over multiple dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution for now:

I actually went with the configuration from above. I fixed the problem within my `main` project with the use of the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- unpacks i18 resources to be used by the main project -->
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-backend-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>              
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                <excludes>**/*.class</excludes>
                <includes>**/i18n/**/*.properties</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It's not very handy, as I need to declare every module as an `artefactItem` but it works. It will copy the translation files from each dependency to the `main` project. Until I find a better solution, this will have to do.